# Mongo find based on value in array of objects

Tags: mongodb

the documents looks like :

```
{
  name: 'abc',
  types: [
     {name:'Large',stock:true}, 
     {name:'XLarge',stock:false},
     {name:'XXLarge',stock:true}
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to figure out the query to return all documents which are out of stock.

Something like : `.find({types:{{$nin:{stock:true}}})`
Can I somehow do that?

Comment: Do you want you example document to be returned or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 6):

You can query using positional operator like this:

```
db.collection.find({'types.stock':{$ne:true}})
```

`$nin` operator is used for finding elements not in a particular array. `$ne` (not equal to) is a much better operation in your case.